# Get Data from Mysql Database to array in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

hi i have database with users data and i need this data get to my array in C# with cyklus

this code

```
MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE user_id='1'";
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    userdata[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[i]);
    i++;               


 }


 dataReader.Close();
```

but this work only one, for id 0 after nothing , someone help me? thanks so much

i need that data reader read all colums and give info from colum 0 to userdata[0], colum 1 to userdata[1] etc....

Comment: Are you sure your `user_id='0'` returns data? And you don't need `i` and increment it. `.Read` method reads your data _row by row_. In your example, this reads **only** first column of first row, second column of the second row, third column of the third row _etc_.. Also you can use `GetXXX()` methods of `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should use `dataReader.GetInt32(i)` rather than `Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[i])`.

Comment: This code will read column 0 from row 0, then column 1 from row 1, column 2 from row 2... What do you want it to do? Read one column from every row? Or read all columns from each row?

Comment: Read all colums from row with user_id='1'

Comment: Are you expecting to get *exactly* one row back from the database? And what columns are you expecting? What are their types?

Comment: I want back all colums from row with colum user_id = 1 , all colums are type int

Answer (score 0):

The datareader is reading from the field index for the current record.  You'll want to change dataReader[i] to dataReader[0], but continue to increase the index for the userdata variable.

It should look something like this:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    userdata[i++] = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]); //i++ can be included right in the array index.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    userdata[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]);
    i++;
    userdata[i] = Convert.ToString(dataReader[1]);//Change the datatype base on the data type of the field in the table
    i++;               


}
```

Comment: Do you want to assign the value from `dataReader[1]` to another variable? Otherwise you will overwrite the value from `dataReader[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `dataReader.Read()` means "Go to the database and get the next row". It sounds like you want to get all the data from one row.

I think what you want is more like:

```
dataReader.Read();
for (int i=0; i</*number of columns that you have*/; i++) {
    userData[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[i]);
}
```

Notice that `dataReader.Read()` is only called once, so you are only going to see data from the first row - the row where `user_id = 1` (note: I am assuming that there is only one row where this is true, your question/comments imply this but doesn't say it explicitly).